# How to increase line height in NetBeans 7?

Tags: netbeans, css

I found a hack how to increase it in 6.9, but it does not work in NetBeans 7. Is there any way to increase the space between the lines in ver. 7? Please help, googled it too - no info about it :/

Comment: I think that is not an option. Do you know of other IDEs that support this? I suggest to get better glasses or a bigger monitor.

Comment: Strange :) I found this question because google sent me to. I was trying to find a solution to make the line spacing more dense.

Comment: @OliBlogger Sumblime Text 2

Comment: @OliBlogger , please... Text is easier to read with 150% line spacing, like in books. Sadly software/website designers rarely keep this in mind.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here you go,

1. Find `org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml` in `~/.netbeans/x.x/config/Editors/Preferences` where `x.x` is your netbeans version.
2. Add this xml markup just above `</editor-preferences>` or anywhere if you know what you doing.

```xml
<entry javaType="java.lang.Float" name="line-height-correction" xml:space="preserve">  
    <value><![CDATA[1.4]]></value>  
</entry>
```

Comment: On Mac, I found the file under ~/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/config/editors/Preferences/org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml. You will need to change 8.2 to whatever version you have, but 8.2 is common as of today.

Comment: It works in NetBeans 8.2 too, I found it in ```C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\Editors\Preferences```. I have to enable show hidden item :)

Comment: thanks it is realy work , for any ppl how look for it now in 2020 -i bean couple years to find post like that , on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you will look for org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml  inside snap/netbeans/common/data/11.2/config/Editirs/Preferences

Answer (score 1):

In Apache Netbeans  14,

I was installed it via .sh file

I figure out how to change/add editor custom preferences as well
open

```
/home/username/.netbeans/14/config/Editors/Preferences/
```

and open

```
org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml
```

then  add a new entry

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Float" name="line-height-correction" xml:space="preserve">  
    <value><![CDATA[1.5]]></value>  
</entry>
```

Have a nice edit.

Answer (score 0):

@pengemizt answer is greate but it is long time now 
for netbeans 11.2
on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you will look for

```
 org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml
```

inside

```
 snap/netbeans/common/data/11.2/config/Editors/Preferences
```

You can change this

```
<![CDATA[1.4]]>
```

as you like for me I make it 1.5

```
<![CDATA[1.5]]>
```